# The whole background is going down when the key board is going down

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

When we are setting the keyboard to go down it is shifting the whole background down. 
The html for the UI is:

```
<body ng-app="MobileApp" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <div ng-view style="margin:0px; padding:0px;height:100%;"></div>
</body>
```

In the div inside the body the whole section part is getting replace each time when the app navigates from screen to screen.

```
<section class="main_wrapper create_account mainContainer">
  ....
</section>
```

When we are closing the keyboard the whole body is going down as a result of which there are some UI distortions.

The css for the issue is:

```
.main_wrapper.create_account{
 background-image:url(../img/create-account-bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
}
```

And If I add overflow:scroll to the css then the issue is getting fixed but there is jerk when the keyboard is coming up

Comment: Can you provide a working sample code or an url ?

Comment: @lapin I have already provided the sample code.

Comment: @lapin can you provide your skype id so that I can send the code over skype.

Comment: And If I add overflow:scroll to the css then the issue is getting fixed but there is jerk when the keyboard is coming up.

Comment: I can not see what you see. I just get you were talking about mobile keyboard which now makes sens a little more. Can you upload a screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: @lapin As my reputation is low I cannot upload screenshots. Can you provide your mail id so that I can send them to you.

Comment: You can upload your screenshot to a free hosting service and paste the url, you don't need reputation for that. It's better that I'm not the only one that can see it.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/d9t1m00rz/
http://postimg.org/image/r27ghmrjj/
These are the two images @lapin

Comment: Where are the distortions you are talking about ? Did you try background-size: 100% 100%; OR removing height:100%; ?

Comment: Yes. But in both the scenarios it didn't work. @lapin
And Please view the postimg.org/image/r27ghmrjj the whole background is shifted down.

Comment: @lapin can you please help to solve the issue

Comment: Sorry I as said, there is not enough information to help. Try to simulate the same problem on a jsfiddle and it'll be far easier to help.

Comment: The problem cannot be replicated in the JS fiddle. What information do you need? I am just stuck too badly. @lapin

Comment: Can you provide the real url with the working code in action ?

Comment: I have a demo application in which the same problem is occurring. Can you provide your mail id so that I can send you the project. @lapin

Comment: Hey @lapin I have made a demo app in which same problem is occurring. We are also trying from our end. You also please give a try.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3lyioadxf6c2rm/TestSlide.zip

Steps to reproduce.
1. Run the project.
2. Tap on the textarea.
3. Tap on the downkey to close the keyboard(This operation has to be done very fast).